# If $F(2) = 5$, $F'(2) = 4$, $H(2) = 3$, $H'(2) = 4$, find

Tags: calculus

A) $G'(2)$ if $G(z) = F(z) H(z)$.

B) $G'(2)$ if $G(w) = F(w)/H(w)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explain what you need. If you need to determine $G'(2)$ where $G(z)=F(z)H(z)$ or $G(w)=F(w)/H(w)$, then you can simply use the formulas
$$
G'(z)=\left ( F(z)H(z) \right )'=F'(z)H(z)+F(z)H'(z)
$$
and
$$
G'(w)=\left ( \frac{F(w)}{H(w)} \right )'=\frac{F'(w)H(z)-F(w)H'(w)}{(H(w))^{2}}.
$$